# Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel' not found - laravel

Tags: laravel

P.S the laravel project works fine. But only while running cronjob, it gives following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel' not found in /var/www/abc.com.np/project/app/Console/Kernel.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/abc.com.np/project/app/Console/Kernel.php on line 16
```

**Deleting vendor and composer.lock and composer install or composer update doesnot work.**

**sudo composer dumpauto  did not work.**

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "intervention/image": "^2.7",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.4",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "realrashid/sweet-alert": "^5.0",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.5",
        "spatie/laravel-sluggable": "^2.6",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

**cronjob execution:** crontab -e

```
*  *  *  *  * php -q /var/www/abc.com.np/project/app/Console/Kernel.php && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: i guess you have wrong way to test cronjob or run Kernel.php this file directly. if you want to test cronjob，you can do this command. ```shell
php artisan schedule:run
```
or
use Log class. if can't help you. please tell me how do you test cronjob or kernel.php?

Comment: how is this command being executed?

Comment: @lagbox  *  *  *  *  * php -q /var/www/abc.com.np/project/app/Console/Kernel.php && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: you don't run the kernel file, you don't run any files directly in the project ... either execute an artisan command or run the scheduler via artisan, as autoloading has to happen and the entire framework needs to be booted

Comment: I followed laravel doc here:   https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler    Isn't it how we run scheduler in the server? Sorry I didn't get you.

Comment: no where there does it say to execute the Kernel ... that is just the artisan command for the scheduler

Comment: How can we execute Kernel (linux server)?

Comment: you don't, you execute an artisan command